# Computer Power supply not powering when connecting power pin to the ground

Tags: power-supply

I have an old power supply which hasn't a power button to turn on/off.It is made by Enlight corporation.The model is: ATX-1123B 230W.

I found an image with the ATX power supply pinouts.Here it is:

[image]

As you can see, the green pin(PS_ON#) is for turning on the power supply. You connect the green pin to a ground pin (COM pins) and the power supply should turn on. But in my case ,it wont! But it will turn on if i connect the yellow pin(+12VCD) to the purple pin(+5VSB). Why does this happen. Can it damage my power supply??I can't get any power if i turn it on by connecting the purple pin to the yellow pin. The purple pin is "+5 VDC Standby Voltage" and the yellow pin "+12 VDC". I think that this is wrong and can damage the supply

Comment: Does it try to come up and then go off again, or is it completely dead?  Is there any sound at all?

Comment: When i try turning it on from the green pin and black nothing happens, but when i try from the purple and yellow pin it turns on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not turn on by connecting 5V standby output to 12V output, you are just back-feeding the fan with 5V supply. Don't do this as it may cause damage. Connecting PS_ON to GND should work unless the power supply is broken or it needs a small load to run properly.

Comment: THX for the anwear!

Comment: where to put the small load? How small the load should be

Comment: Many (most?) low cost switching power supplies have one main output that requires a minimum load current, usually around 10% of its maximum current rating.  This is a consequence of optimizing the transformer and control circuits for ultra-low production cost.  If you can find a datasheet for the supply, it will list the minimum load conditions.

Comment: Thank you a lot!